# VHDL impure keyword

Tags: vhdl, best-practice

I have vhdl code along these lines (explanation below):

```
architecture arc of anEntity is
  signal x1_sig : T;
  signal x2_sig : T2;

  function test(x1: T, x2: T2) return boolean is
  begin
    if complicatedConditionWith x1 and x2 then
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    end if;
  end function;
begin
  p1: process (...) is
    impure function test return boolean is
    begin
      return test(x1_sig,x2_sig);
    end function;
  begin
    ...
    if test then --occurs several times
    ...
  end process;
end architecture;
```

For ease of writing and readability I put a complicated condition into a function. Since I am lazy and always use the same `signals` with that function, I added a shorthand to the process were I use this function mainly. However modelsim complained about accesses to a signal from a `pure` function, so I added the `impure` modifier. To my knowledge this is telling the compiler that the function might have side effects, even though, since I access everything only reading (in c one could define the function parameters as `const`) I consider my function free of side effects.
Might the addition of `impure` have negative side effects on the synthesis result?

Comment: What happens if you replace `complicatedConditionWith x1 and x2` with a simple condition?

Comment: @Justin: The condition is not the problem here (I think). And it is actually rather long than complicated. (it reads something like : `x1.state = READY_S or (x1.state = WAITMEM_S and x2.writeReady='1') or (x1.state = FETCHMEM_S and x2.check='1')`) If you could tell me how you hope changing the condition could awnser my question, that is about the impact of the `impure` keyword I am all ears.

Comment: I don't actually know any VHDL, so I won't have an answer for you...just suggestions to debug. I wasn't sure if you had additional function calls in your condition. Perhaps you do...do the .state and .writeReady accessors might somehow refer to external 'impure' state? Try creating a minimal complete example that shows the problem. You may figure out the answer yourself in doing so.  Can you replace the condition with a constant true or false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "pure" function, as well as having no side effects, also returns the same result every time it is evaluated with the same arguments. The importance of this is to allow optimisations : the compiler is permitted to cache the result, compute it outside the inner loop, reorder computations etc without affecting correctness.

A function that reads a signal (if you were updating it, that would be a side effect!) will return results depending on that signal value, therefore it cannot be pure. Declaring it impure is correct and will not affect synthesis results.

(Arguably better is to keep it pure and pass in the signal as a parameter; however if that adds clutter and hinders readability, the current approach is better)

Comment: The first sentence of this awnser was key, I overlooked the same result same arguments part (x1_sig and x2_sig are only implicit arguments...).